# Use of variable SET statement in stored procedures compiles but fires exception at runtime

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variable-assignment

In a Snowflake SQL-stored procedure, I would like to SET value of a variable like the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_SP_SQL();
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_SP_SQL()
RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
  LANGUAGE SQL
AS
  DECLARE
    retValue VARCHAR;
  BEGIN
    SET retVal = '';
[...]
```

Everything rocks at compile time but fails at runtime with the following exception

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line *x* at position *y* :
> Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'SET'.

despite [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html) says this to be possible

Can someone gently explain to the noob of me? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a SQL stored procedure use [LET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/let.html) instead of SET. The syntax for stored procedures (also known as Snowflake Scripting) is different from interactive SQL. The valid commands in SQL scripting are described in the [Snowflake Scripting Reference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference-snowflake-scripting.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying that quick. Actually there were multiple errors in my store procedure code 
As you can see in the code sample, there was a typo (retVal vs retValue) that explained the not-so-meaningful "Unsupported statement type 'SET'" exception, that was pretty intelligible once I noticed retval wasn't even declared... On top of that, colons were missing in front of the equal sign. And I won't get much more ashamed at telling you how many bugs were taking place in the unquoted stored procedure code 
Thanks anyway!